# Illegal invocation with $.get inside $.ajax success

Tags: jquery, ajax

Attempting to fetch some content if this route returns true, however I'm getting `Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation` for the `$.get` line -- would anybody happen to know why?

```
$.ajax({
  url: "/route_to_check_if_item_exists/",
  type: "GET",
  success: function(){
    console.log('Item exists! Now fetch it:');

    $.get($('#articles').data('url'), {
      after: $('#articles')
    });
  },
  error: function() {
    console.log('Uh oh');
  }
});
```

Comment: What exactly is `after: $('#articles')` supposed to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only multi-argument syntax for `$.get` is `jQuery.get( url [, data ] [, success ] [, dataType ] )`
where `data` can be a simple object, however you can't send a DOM element, or a jQuery object

```
$.get($('#articles').data('url'), {
  after: $('#articles')
});
```

Note that you're sending `$('#articles')`, which is a jQuery wrapper around a DOM element, and that can't be sent, hence an illegal invocation

It's not very clear what you're actually trying to do, but if you're trying to insert the content of the request, that would be more like

```
$.get($('#articles').data('url'), function( data ) {
    $('#articles').after( data )
});
```